# Track first keypress event

Tags: javascript, keypress

For reasons I have to rely on `keypress` instead of `keydown/keyup`. `keypress` repeatedly fires events if the key is pressed. How to track only the first press on a key?

For `keydown/keyup` this would not be a problem, since there is a dedicated `keyup` event. But this is not the case for `keypress`.

Comment: Is the tag [[tag:coffeescript]] really relevant for this question? If not, please remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Check the 'repeat' property of the event (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent)

If it's false then it's the first event, true otherwise.

Example using jquery:

```
$("#someid").on("keypress", function(e){
    if(!e.originalEvent.repeat){console.log("first keypress")};
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It's true that the "repeat" attribute doesn't work in Safari. It's only available in Gecko-based browsers. In lieu of that, try this (if you absolutely MUST use "keypress" instead of the alternatives):

```
var lastCode = -1;
$("#someid").on("keypress", function(e) {
  var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (lastCode !== code) {
    // do something
  }
  lastCode = code;
});
```

Comment: This sample won't work for multiple keys! The reason for `keypress` are characters like `?` - How to detect such characters independent from the user's keyboard?

Comment: Actually, this sample DOES work for multiple keys. It will ensure that you never press the same key twice in a row. Isn't that what you wanted?